# busybox stty: standard input: cannot perform all requested operations?

Tags: tty, busybox

When I specified `stty isig`, the following error occurred. I found a [similar problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487880/tmux-rails-stty-standard-input-unable-to-perform-all-requested-operation) but did not resolve it. I searched for a lot of information but I'm not sure what's going on. I have no clue, can anyone help me? I am using Busybox's own `stty`.

```shellsession
# tty
/dev/tty1

# stty isig
stty: standard input: cannot perform all requested operations.

# stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 37; columns 100; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

Comment: Add the output of `stty -a` to your question ? If Busybox is acting as your shell, it may need to prevent you from changing how it handles signals.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I have already added it. Busybox preventing? What should I do then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customized Linux systems cannot use crtl+c to terminate ping commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/768117/customized-linux-systems-cannot-use-crtlc-to-terminate-ping-commands)

Comment: @Vilinkameni Obviously, these are two issues.

Comment: It is the same issue, there is no need to open a separate question. If you feel that the original question needs additional details, edit it or explain in the comments.

Comment: Something of an X-Y question. The terminal is configured to pass intr, quit, and susp. but Busybox refuses to let you set a 1-bit boolean `isig`. Why do you need to set isig?

Comment: See the Busybox FAQ at: `https://busybox.net/FAQ.html#job_control`

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Because some commands cannot be terminated by `ctr+c`, such as `ping` and `taskset`.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Emmm, I saw the connection you sent and it said there was an issue with the `/dev/console`, but mine is `/dev/tty1`.